# Cannot set scope Google sign in on Android

Tags: android, google-api, access-token, google-signin

I use Google API for signin on Android app.

Code here:

```
SignInButton btnLogin = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

Scope[] scopes = new Scope[2];
scopes[0] = new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly");
scopes[1] = new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly");

btnLogin.setScopes(scopes);
```

**Sign in success with access token**, but the access token only default scopes:

```
"userinfo.profile" & "userinfo.email" & "auth/plus.me"
```

Can you help me to get 2 scopes:

```
"/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly" & "/auth/contacts.readonly"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can refer to the following syntax:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)) // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)) // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

More details at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder#requestScopes(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope,%20com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope...)). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank BNK (-v-). => .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly")). It worked!

Answer (score 3):

You can add multiple Scopes in requestScopes().

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN), new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```